# Installing Java on online Gitlab ci

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, gitlab, gitlab-ci

Here is my .gitlab-ci.yml script.

```
before_script:
  - uname -a
  - apt-get install default-jre default-jdk openjdk-7-jre openjdk-7-jdk
  - java -version
  - export MODE="service"
  - export PID_FOLDER="/var/run/gitlab-runner-test"

dev:
  script:
    - chmod +x gradlew
    - ./gradlew assembleDebug
```

I am trying to run the script on gitlab.com page to compile a android project. I checked with some alterations to my script that there is no java installed on the ci
 linux Linux runner-8a2f473d-project-881036-concurrent-0 4.5.0-coreos-r1 #2 SMP Thu May 5 07:27:26 UTC 2016 x86_64 GNU/Linux.

I tried installing java, just like a sample which was shown for ruby, but it does not work, and gives an Unable to locate package error.

I am not sure what should be the package as it seems like a ubuntu system, but the command which works on my ubuntu does not work here.

This is not a local installation.

Comment: Don't you need `sudo` to install with `apt-get`? Also, what does your script do? Does it perform the `uname` part?

Comment: Yes, I get the info 
linux Linux runner-8a2f473d-project-881036-concurrent-0 4.5.0-coreos-r1 #2 SMP Thu May 5 07:27:26 UTC 2016 x86_64 GNU/Linux 
on uname part. 
It does nto run with sudo as it seems to be a custom env which does not have sudo support.

Comment: So where does it stop running then? `uname` is fine but then `apt-get` not?

Comment: Yep I get a unable to locate package error. Sorry shall format my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you should be able to use the `image` feature described [here](http://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html). I found success with the `anapsix/alpine-java:jdk8` Docker image.

I am using my own Docker gitlab-runner with a custom Docker image as I need Maven with Oracle java. I'm not 100% on if the shared runner on gitlab.com allows you to use your own image.

My Dockerfile for that (which I upload to Gitlab and use their new Docker container register feature)

```
FROM anapsix/alpine-java:jdk8

ENV MAVEN_VERSION 3.3.3

RUN apk update && apk upgrade && apk add curl wget bash tar rsync openssh-client

RUN mkdir -p /usr/share/maven \
  && curl -fsSL http://apache.osuosl.org/maven/maven-3/$MAVEN_VERSION/binaries/apache-maven-$MAVEN_VERSION-bin.tar.gz \
    | tar -xzC /usr/share/maven --strip-components=1 \
  && ln -s /usr/share/maven/bin/mvn /usr/bin/mvn \
  && rm -rf /tmp/* /var/cache/apk/*;

ENV MAVEN_HOME /usr/share/maven

ENTRYPOINT []
CMD ["bash"]
```